# How can I ensure that the axios get response is only executed once as well as accessible when passing data to child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, react-hooks

Whenever I sent the `uploadsData` variable from `App.js` into the `<Gallery data={uploadsData}/>} />` component via a prop, it gets called more than one time.  The first array contains nothing but the next two arrays contain the correct data.

[image]

Furthermore, whenever I hover over the blue `!`, I get that warning illustrated in the screenshot.  This means I can never properly access this object properly.

How can I make so that it's executed once and only once so I can access the object in the proper way?

I thought having a `[]` in `useEffect()` (2nd param) as the dependency would cause pave the way for this to only be executed once?

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read.  I'm open to any sort of feedback including code improvements/changes that are considered better practice

Here's `App.js`:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import '../../sass/HomePage/homePage.scss';
import LoginRegister from "./LoginRegister/LoginRegister";
import Gallery from "./Gallery/Gallery";
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

const App = () => {
    const [uploadsData, setUploadsData] = useState([]);
    let { push } = useHistory();
    let authToken = Cookies.get('token');

    useEffect(() => {
        getUploads();
    },[]);

    function getUploads() {
        const headers = {
            "Accept": 'application/json',
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
        }

        axios.get('http://localhost:8005/api/get-uploads', {headers})
            .then(resp => {
                let uData = [...uploadsData,resp];
                setUploadsData(uData);
                if (authToken !== null) {
                    push('/gallery');
                } else {
                    console.log("User's NOT authenticated, returning to login view");
                    push('/');
                }
            }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={LoginRegister} />
                <Route component={() => <Gallery data={uploadsData}/>} />
            </Switch>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;

if (document.getElementById('example')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Router><App/></Router>, document.getElementById('example'));
}
```

Here's `Gallery.js`:

```
import React from 'react';

const Gallery = (data) => {    
    return (
        <>    
            {console.log(data)}
        </>
    );
}

export default Gallery;
```

Answer (score 0):

Show the component when data is prepared:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import '../../sass/HomePage/homePage.scss';
import LoginRegister from "./LoginRegister/LoginRegister";
import Gallery from "./Gallery/Gallery";
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

const App = () => {
    const [uploadsData, setUploadsData] = useState([]);
    let { push } = useHistory();
    let authToken = Cookies.get('token');

    useEffect(() => {
        getUploads();
    },[]);

    function getUploads() {
        const headers = {
            "Accept": 'application/json',
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
    }

    axios.get('http://localhost:8005/api/get-uploads', {headers})
        .then(resp => {
            let uData = [...uploadsData,resp];
            setUploadsData(uData);
            if (authToken !== null) {
                push('/gallery');
            } else {
                console.log("User's NOT authenticated, returning to login view");
                push('/');
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={LoginRegister} />
                <Route component={() => <> {uploadsData?.data?.length && <Gallery data={uploadsData}/> }</>} />
            </Switch>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;

if (document.getElementById('example')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Router><App/></Router>, document.getElementById('example'));
}
```

And use memo to avoid of rerender component when props don't have changes:

```
import React, {memo} from 'react';

const Gallery = (data) => {    
  return (
    <>    
        {console.log(data)}
    </>
  );
}

export default memo(Gallery);
```

Comment: This seems like an interesting solution, but when I tried it - it gave me a blank page with no errors displaying in the console.  I'm trying to troubleshoot why.